# PostgreSQL Query: Use a json field to filter entries before grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a Postgres table with the following schema,

```
create table exam_info
(
  "venue" text not null,    //value: "A", "B", "C", "D"
  "time" int,               //epoch time
  "examData" jsonb not null  
);
```

here is some example entries for examData column

```
{"id":"e73kf", "data":{"subject":"Science","year":"grade5"}}
{"id":"e3dsa", "data":{"subject":"English","year":"grade3"}}
```

I would like to find out for a specific subject(Science), how many exam has been hosted in each venue in a specific time range

```
subject     venue     count
"Science"     A          10
"Science"     B           5
"Science"     C           7
"Science"     D          11
```

When I tried to add a condition where exam = "Science" in the following query, an error `column exam does not exist` showed up.

```
SELECT
    "examData" -> 'data' -> 'subject' as exam,
    venue,
    count(venue)
FROM
    exam_info
WHERE
    time >= '   ' AND time < '    '
GROUP BY
    exam,venue
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: what is "exam" column in your group by ? you don't have exam column in your table,  remove it and you are ok

Comment: Your query works just fine. All the column names you selected (exam, venue) in the SELECT section are available to be used in the GROUP BY section

Comment: Note thta `count(*)` will be slightly faster than `count(venue)`

Comment: @eshirvana check the SELECT section, I have defined the json field "subject" as exam. The query itself runs fine, the error only showed up when I want to add the condition where exam = "Science"

Comment: Yes the query itself runs fine, the error only showed up when I want to add the condition where exam = "Science", and I would like to know how I can add this condition to the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in comment , you are referring to another problem than your original question,
anyways , you can't refer to "exam" in the where clause because you can't use column aliases in the where clause, but you can refer it the way you build the column :

```
SELECT
    "examData" -> 'data' -> 'subject' as exam,
    venue,
    count(venue)
FROM
    exam_info
WHERE
    time >= '   ' AND time < '    '
    and "examData" -> 'data' -> 'subject'  ='"Math"' -- <--
GROUP BY
    exam,venue
```